# MST region and CST virtual bridge priority

Tags: cisco, spanning-tree, ieee-802.1s

In `Multiple Spanning Tree`, `802.1s`, an MST region appears to the external world (another MST region, a 802.1d or 802.1w switch) as a single (virtual) bridge, using its IST instance.

What is the priority of this virtual bridge? How do we configure it?

What need to be configured on all members of the MST region to ensure this MST region virtual bridge will always be elected as root bridge?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Set the root priority on the 0 instance:

```
spanning-tree mst 0 root primary
```

This will insure this bridge has the lowest priority of any other switch in the region.

> To configure a switch to become the root, use the spanning-tree mst
>   instance-id root global configuration command to modify the switch
>   priority from the default value (32768) to a significantly lower value
>   so that the switch becomes the root switch for the specified
>   spanning-tree instance. When you enter this command, the switch checks
>   the switch priorities of the root switches. Because of the extended
>   system ID support, the switch sets its own priority for the specified
>   instance to 24576 if this value will cause this switch to become the
>   root for the specified spanning-tree instance.

[Source](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2950/software/release/12-1_11_yj4/configuration/guide/lrescg/swmstp.pdf)

Comment: thanks @Ron Trunk , but my problem is not in the region, it is regarding the whole region interacting with other switches outside of the region. –

Answer (score 2):

CIST Root Bridges Election Process

When a switch boots up, it declares itself as CIST Root and CIST Regional Root and announces this fact in outgoing BPDUs. The switch will adjust its decision upon reception of better information and continue advertising the best known CIST Root and CIST Regional Root on all internal ports. On the boundary ports, the switch advertises only the CIST Root Bridge ID and CIST External Root Path Cost thus hiding the details of the region’s internal topology.

CIST External Root Path Cost is the cost to reach the CIST Root across the links connecting the boundary ports – i.e. the inter-region links. When a BPDU is received on an internal port, this cost is not changed. When a BPDU is received on a boundary port, this cost is adjusted based on the receiving boundary port cost. In result, the CIST External Root Path Cost is propagated unmodified inside any region.

Only a boundary switch could be elected as the CIST Regional Root, and this is the switch with the lowest cost to reach the CIST Root. If a boundary switch hears better CIST External Root Path cost received on its internal link, it will relinquish its role of CIST Regional Root and start announcing the new metric out of its boundary ports.

Every boundary switch needs to properly block its boundary ports. If the switch is a CIST Regional Root, it elects one of the boundary ports as the “CIST Root port” and blocks all other boundary ports. If a boundary switch is not the CIST Regional Root, it will mark the boundary ports as CIST Designated or Alternate. The boundary port on a non regional-root bridge becomes designated only if it has superior information for the CIST Root: better External Root Path cost or if the costs are equal better CIST Regional Root Bridge ID. This follows the normal rules of STP process.

As a result of CIST construction, every region will have one switch having single port unblocked in the direction of the CIST Root. This switch is the CIST Regional Root. All boundary switches will advertise the region’s CIST Regional Root Bridge ID out of their non-blocking boundary ports. From the outside perspective, the whole region will look like a single virtual bridge with the Bridge ID = CIST Regional Root ID and single root port elected on the CIST Regional Root switch.

The region that contains the CIST Root will have all boundary ports unblocked and marked as CIST designated ports. Effectively the region would look like a virtual root bridge with the Bridge ID equal to CIST Root and all ports being designated. Notice that the region with CIST Root has CIST Regional Root equal to CIST Root as they share the same lowest bridge priority value across all regions.

Have a look at the diagram below. It demonstrates the CIST topology calculated from the physical topology we outlined above. First, SW1-1 is elected as the CIST Root as it has the lowest Bridge ID among all bridges in all regions. This automatically makes region 1 a virtual bridge with all boundary ports unblocked. Next, SW2-1 and SW3-1 are elected as the CIST Regional Roots in their respective regions. Notice that SW3-1 and SW2-3 have equal External Costs to reach the CIST Root but SW3-1 wins the CIST Regional Root role due to lower priority. Keep in mind that in the topology with multiple MSTP regions, every region that does not contain the CIST Root has to change the IST Root election process and make IST Root equal to CIST Regional Root.

[source](http://blog.ine.com/2010/02/22/understanding-mstp/#CIST)

[image]